# cellForRowAtIndexPath is not being called on iOS-tableView remains empty

Tags: ios, uitableview, populate

I want to display the contents of an array in the tableView but the control never comes into cellForRowAtIndexPath. This method is where I add

`cell.textLabel.text = [self.itemArray indexPath.row];`

Please advise.
how do you populate the table?

Comment: are you sure it's not being called try putting a NSLog(@"TEST") see the output. That sounds a lot like the table view datasource being empty the first time sow you might want to check if the array has objects saved.

Comment: How many rows are there in tableView.

Comment: How can I find out the number of rows? numberOfRowsInSection returned 0 earlier then I changed it to 1.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

1. Are you sure it's not being called try putting a `NSLog(@"TEST")` see the output.
2. That sounds a lot like the table view `datasource` being empty the first time sow you might want to check if the array has objects saved.
3. Also you might want to check and see if `numberOfSectionsInTableView` table to be set at 1, and `numberOfRowsInSection` not equal 0. If `numberOfRowsInSection`  returns 0 then the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` may not be called.

Comment: oh my numberOfRowsInSection returns 0

Comment: I changed it to 1 and I could see something in the tableView. Thank you very much.

Comment: But, how can I select a row? As in a cell in the table for further operations? Currently, I'm unable to select anything. I just see some text in the cell of a row. I want to select it.

Comment: if you want to be able to select a row you have to set the tables showselectionontouch to on (you can set this from the code  or using Interface builder you can check it to on), after that you have to write custom code do handle the selection in the didSelectRowAtIndexPath function

Comment: 3rd point is very helpful, logically  if numberOfSectionsInTableView table  set at > 1, then numberOfRowsInSection should be > 0

Comment: 3rd point is very helpful indeed. I believe if number of sections returns 0, it doesn't bother calling anything else. +1 for keeping me from pulling more hair out.

Answer (score 3):

Have you implemented the other methods in UITableViewController:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [self.itemArray count];
}
```

If these return 0, then your cellForRowAtIndexPath method wont be called.

Comment: in your case, that would be: self.itemArray, I beleive . Will update.

Comment: oh yes you're right! I understand now. Thank you very much!! Are you familiar with Dropbox?

Comment: I have a problem: The count turns out to be 0 although I am doing [self.itemArray addObject:FILENAME] in viewDidLoad.